# Noise issues Atmega power line

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pcb, noise, ground-plane

I have designed a PCB that has a Atemga328 chip, connected to 6 logic level MosFETs via the PWM lines of the chip. The board is primarily designed to run long lines of led strips. Turning them on, fading etc.

The board has been thoroughly tested, and the only issue discovered is that when there is a big load (~4A per mosfet), the atmega chip becomes unresponsive. This is exacerbated when driven with PWM signals rather than leaving the load permanently on.

On inspection, there is a huge amount of noise on the power lines that correspond to the switching of the mosfets (I cannot produce screenshots at this point in time).

Upon doing research I have found a couple points of possible failure with my design.

1. The use of a 7805 regulator for atmega chip. Although I would like to keep this cheap do to wide availability.
2. The use of a common ground plane for the power and digital grounds.

My question, is will separating the digital and power ground planes would help with the noise?  And what other steps can I take to reduce noise in the power lines?

[image: board layout without planes]
board layout without planes

[image: board layout with ground plane]
board layout with ground plane

[image: board layout with 12V plane]
board layout with 12V plane

[image]

Notes:

1. The board is designed to use a 12V rail for the MosFETs.
2. Two layer design.

Comment: Without a schematic and some information about  the mode of operation, these layouts are virtually worthless

Comment: Two layer design?

Comment: ya 2 layer design. Coming with edits

Comment: Don't expect to a specific answer, this is a serious problem requiring a serious debug session. The thing i can see is that you have significant capacitance between your outputs and GND. That means that when you have pulses of voltage across this capacitance- pulses of current spreading in GND plane. Can easily cause voltage spikes on anything. Including through decoupling capacitors.

Comment: How fast are you switching? Can you consider slowing down the gate even more? Is a snubber on the output acceptable? Also +1 on what everyone else says about sprinkling capacitors on every rail.

Comment: Oh by the way, maybe a pulse of 4A just dips the main voltage? It could be a simpler theory, easy to test and solve. And this is how it would be related to load current

Comment: @winny I'm using Arduino code, so I think it's 500Hz. I can slow things down, but the idea at the moment is to make a new version of the board that is less susceptible to these issues.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum ya, I agree. I'm hoping for suggestions on a good route to take. 

I have done a test powering the logic side with a separate power supply and the problem still persists.

Comment: Well... You will probably not get away without oscilloscope, synchronization on your pwm and watching all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Good. If I where you, I would reserve 0603 series R and parallel C to the gate for tuning later on, preferably four layer, shorten all tracks as much as possible and sprinkle capacitors on every rail.

Comment: @winny is it standard practice to add a parallel capacitor to the gate of a mosfet? would that not place the mosfet into its linear region?

Comment: Not permanently. You are just slowing the switching down if needed, and from your problem description, it sounds like the dV/dt is the source of your problems. Being able to offset the Miller capacitance effect comes in the same capacitor placement too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decoupling capacitors for your Atmega should be directly across the supply pins and as close as possible to the pins. Try soldering a 100nF directly across pins 7 and 8 and also 20 and 22.

If you intend to relayout the PCB you need to think about getting the high current path off the groundplane and as short as possible. You have three sets of two outputs and three ground connects. Change the output ordering and group these as three sets of output-ground-output the ground is connected directly and only to the two transistors driving that output. You then add a single point connect from your groundplane to a point between the transistor sources to enable the gate drive. Use a separate logic ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have huge noise before 7805 it's OK, but when noise on 5v power line you will need add 4,7 - 10uF ceramic capacitor.
2. Check noise on mosfet gate. Noise can goes thru mosfet's gate straight on gpio. Resistors between gpio and gate can help you.